# Scala: Regex of finding max string not ending with certain String

Tags: java, regex, scala

Given a String, I need to find out the maximum String *at the beginning* which contains **anything** in the original String, but stop when seeing the defined pattern.

For example, given "**\n**www.{Google}.comcomxxxcom" as the String and "com" as the ending pattern,

we want "**\n**www.{Google}." as the result.

I tried to do something like

```
val filter = """[\\s\\S]*(?!com)""".r
filter.findAllIn("\nwww.{Google}.com").toArray
```

but the result is not what I want.

I've also tried other possibilities but failed. Anyone can help?

Comment: It works in my example, but if the String given is "xxxcomcom" then the result would be "xxxcom", which still contains the forbidden pattern...

Comment: Then you need a lazy quantifier, `"""[\s\S]*?(?=com)""".r`

Comment: It gets to the desired answer, but there are some empty Strings in some cases. Any method to get rid of them?

Comment: Could you please post a sample string with expected output?

Comment: When the input String is "xxcomcom{com", the resultant Array is Array(xx, "", om, "", om{, "") with 3 empty String elements.

Comment: BTW, what did you mean by the "maximum" string? Maybe you want to split with `com` and grab the longest item? See https://ideone.com/o6ViiR

Comment: So what is the expected output for `"xxcomcom{com"`?

Comment: I mean the longest one at the front, so "xx" is the answer. But those "om"s are totally understandable, I just wonder about those empty Strings.

Comment: See the updated answer then.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that, but what if I could only use regex... That's why I was using negative lookahead.

Comment: You cannot use a regex to find the longest substring from multiple substrings (that are also valid matches) in a string. You should extract all  matches and then grab the longest using a programming feature, not a regex.

Comment: If your expected match is always the first one, just use [`"""^[\s\S]+?(?=com)""".r`](https://ideone.com/gmXyrU).

Comment: I see. Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
val filter = """^[\s\S]+?(?=com)""".r
val s = "\nwww.{Google}.comcomxxxcom"
print(filter.findFirstIn(s))
// => Some(
www.{Google}.)
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/gmXyrU)

**Details**

- `^` - the start of a string anchor
- `[\s\S]+?` - Group 1: any 1+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first
- `com` - is matched and consumed.

Note that since you need a single match from a string, you can use `findFirstIn` rather than `findAllIn`.